# Django REST Framework - Render multiple views into the same template

Tags: templates, view, django-rest-framework

I want to have a template which has a listing of objects in the column on the left while showing a detail of an object at the same time. Can I somehow make use of generic `ListAPIView` and `RetrieveAPIView`? In REST API, a client would just do two requests and compose the data together itself. Is a similar approach possible using `TemplateHTMLRenderer`?

Answer (score 0):

I think, there are two ways of doing it.

The most common way is to make two async requests on frontend (one for list, second for retrieve).

The second way is to go away from REST and overwrite `retrieve` method - it should return both information about specific object and about all objects.

If you want to get HTML, try `StaticHTMLRender`

Comment: The "most common way" will result in the second response completely overwriting the first one, since when using `TemplateHTMLRenderer`, both of those would return a rendered HTML template. And the second way violates the loose coupling principle.

Comment: You should use JSONRenderer instead

Comment: Well, the point is to be able to handle both `text/html` and `application/json`.

Comment: Then use the second way. But usually, modern frontend style - is to use json to get data asynchronously. Developers faced the same problem than you, that if they need data from two sources, they have to remaking methods by putting a big amount of information in the `template_renderer`

Comment: REST API should of course get the data asynchronously, as you say. But the text/html should combine them together. And my question is whether this is possible in Django REST Framework somehow.

Comment: @karlosss - when, you specified, I got this clear. I will update the answer

Comment: Thanks. What is the advantage of `StaticHTMLRenderer` over `TemplateHTMLRenderer`?

Comment: @karlosss - `TemplateHTMLRenderer` returns you a template. In your case you don't need a template, you need simple `html code`